# Refactor Method Complexity in RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I synchronized my app with Code Climate for code review.

lib/models/user/synchrony/basecamp_inc.rb

```
def todo_list(todos,basecamp_account,proj_id)
  todos.map{|todo|
    task = basecamp_tasklist(proj_id,todo['id'],basecamp_account)              
    task_list(task['todos']['remaining'],task['name'],'remain') if task['todos']['remaining'].present?
    task_list(task['todos']['completed'],task['name'],'complete') if task['todos']['completed'].present?
  }
end

def task_list(tasks,todo_list,status) 
  tasks.map{|task|
    task_created(task,todo_list)
    task['assignee'].present? && user_owner?(task['assignee']['name']) ? save_task_activity('was assigned to a',task,todo_list,task['updated_at'],'assign') : [tasks,todo_list,status]
    status == 'complete' && user_owner?(task['completer']['name']) && current_date?(task['completed_at']) ? save_task_activity('finished',task,todo_list,task['completed_at'],'finished') : [tasks,todo_list,status]          
  }
end
```

The codes above were detected by Code Climate as having complex methods. I don't get why Code Climate thought of it as complex. So then, the rank of that code is still a C and I want to refactor it. How can I improve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider moving the following conditions into private methods:

```
task['assignee'].present? && user_owner?(task['assignee']['name']) ? save_task_activity('was assigned to a',task,todo_list,task['updated_at'],'assign') : [tasks,todo_list,status]
status == 'complete' && user_owner?(task['completer']['name']) && current_date?(task['completed_at']) ? save_task_activity('finished',task,todo_list,task['completed_at'],'finished') : [tasks,todo_list,status]
```

You should consider moving the following calls to a single method taking a `status` argument for example:

```
task_list(task['todos']['remaining'], task['name'], 'remain') if task['todos']['remaining'].present?
```

Would be refactored as:

```
def build_task_list(tasks, name, status)
  task_list(tasks, name, status) if task.present?
end

build_task_list(task['todos']['remaining'], task['name'], 'remain')
build_task_list(task['todos']['completed'], task['name'], 'complete')
```

Comment: Thanks will try your suggestion